# Understanding the definition of isometric manifolds

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

[image]

I would like to understand the definition of isometric spacetimes in [this](https://www.lps.uci.edu/~jmanchak/gss.pdf) article on page 3. I do not understand the sentence highlighted. How do we define $\varphi_*$ in plain mathematical language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concepts used are actually two:

1. [Pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)): given a smooth map between two manifolds $M,N$, the pullback is 
   a linear map: $$\varphi^*:T_sN\to T_sM\\
   a\mapsto \varphi^*(a)(x,v_1,\dots,v_s)=a(\varphi(x),\text{d}\varphi(v_1),\dots,\text{d}\varphi(v_n))$$

The pullback is always defined for covariant tensor fields. 
That's enough to define an isomorphism: two Riemannian manifolds $(M,g_M);(N,g_N)$ are isomorphic if $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism between the two of them and $\varphi^*(g_N)=g_M$

2. [Pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)): the idea is the same of point (1). The pushforward, however, is not uniquely defined (or at least not elementary) unless the map $\varphi$ is invertible.
   In such a case, the pushforward is defined as
   $$\varphi_*:T^kM\to T^kM\\
   b^{i_1\dotsi_k}(x)e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_k}\mapsto \varphi_*(b)=
   b^{i_1\dotsi_k}(\varphi^{-1}(y))\text{d}\varphi(e_{i_1})\otimes\dots\otimes \text{d}\varphi(e_{i_k})$$

Given a diffeomorphism, we can combine these two tools to "move" any tensor field from $M$ to $N$: the contravariant part is moved with the pushforward $\varphi_*$ the covariant part with $(\varphi^{-1})^*$

Comment: Thanks, If we are working with pushforward, $\varphi_* (g_{a,b})=g'_{a,b}$ means $g_{a,b}=g'_{\varphi_*(a), \varphi_*(b)}$ for all $p\in M$ and $a,b\in T_p M$? I am not  familiar with the symbols of riemannian geometry. Sorry.

Comment: @amoogae The pushforward is defined for contravariant fields. For covariant fields, we use the inverse of the pullback: $\varphi_*(g_M):=(\varphi^{-1})^*(g_M)$

Comment: @amoogae what you wrote is instead the pullback of $g'$. However, since the map is a diffeomorphism, to ask for $\varphi^*(g_N)=g_M$ is the same as to ask for $g_N=(\varphi^{-1})^*(g_M)=\varphi_*(g_M)$

Comment: @amoogae The idea is that if we are working with a smooth map, we can only send vectors (and to some extent vector fields) forward and covariant fields backward. However, if the map is a diffeomorphism, we can move everything in every direction we desire, by simply taking the inverse.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I lack a lot of foundations... Can you recommend a reference for Riemannian manifold?

Comment: @amoogae Both Lang's book "Differential and Riemannian manifolds" and Lee's one "Introduction to Riemannian manifolds" are excellent references. However, if you wish to obtain other suggestions, you may post a new question asking for references (or look if there is a similar question already). As a side note, at a first (and certainly superficial) read, the article you quote is quite divulgative, so you may not need such an extended background